# I am trying to convert the following Windows .bat code to a .sh code for MAC

Tags: windows, macos, batch-file

I am currently taking a GIS programming class. The directions for using GDAL and ogr to manipulate the data is written for a Windows PC.  I am currently working on a MAC.  I am hoping to get some insight on how to translate the .bat code to a .sh code. Thanks!!

Windows .bat code:

```
cd /d c:\data\PhiladelphiaBaseLayers
set ogr2ogrPath="c:\program files\QGIS Dufour\bin\ogr2ogr.exe"
for %%X in (*.shp) do %ogr2ogrPath% -skipfailures -clipsrc c:\data\PhiladelphiaBaseLayers\clipFeature\city_limits.shp c:\data\PhiladelphiaBaseLayers\clipped\%%X c:\data\PhiladelphiaBaseLayers\%%X
for %%X in (*.shp) do %ogr2ogrPath% -skipfailures -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:3857  c:\data\PhiladelphiaBaseLayers\clippedAndProjected\%%X c:\data\PhiladelphiaBaseLayers\clipped\%%X
```

My mac .sh code:

```
cd ~/Desktop/PhiladelphiaBaseLayers

set ogr2ogrPath="/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/plugins/processing/algs/gdal/ogr2ogr.py" \

for shpfile in *.shp 
do $org2ogrPath$ -skipfailures -clipsrc \
~/Desktop/PhiladelphiaBaseLayers/clipFeature/city_limits.shp \
~/Desktop/PhiladelphiaBaseLayers/clipped/"shpfile2""shpfile" \
~/Desktop/PhiladelphiaBaseLayers/"shpfile2""shpfile"

for shpfile in *.shp 
do $ogr2ogrPath$ -skipfailures -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:3857 \
~/Desktop/PhiladelphiaBaseLayers/clipped/"shpfile2""shpfile"
done
```

Comment: Maybe install VirtualBox for free and a copy of WinXP then just run your Windows code.

Comment: Honestly, I have an old MAC and not sure it has the capabilities of running a VM (it does fine otherwise).  I am hoping to figure out the equivalent syntax of the %%X in this .bat file to a .sh file.  Most everything else I seem to have functioning properly.

Comment: Oh, instead of `%%X` try `"$shpfile"`.

Comment: The syntax is like this... `for shpfile in *.shp; do echo "$shpfile"; done` i.e. no dollar or quotes when assigning a value to a variable, but both when you are using it afterwards. Also, if it is right up against something else and the end of it is indistinguishable from something else, you can add braces too, to show then end if its name, like this `"${shpfile}"`

Comment: Thank you! So I tried this.  I am wondering if is different syntax considering there are two %% in front of the variable? What does that double % mean in front of a possible variable?  @MarkSetchell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have had a try to work out what you are attempting. I think this will be closer, but I don't know what `shpfile2` is in your script - all other problems should be fixed now though.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/Desktop/PhiladelphiaBaseLayers

ogr2ogrPath="/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/plugins/processing/algs/gdal/ogr2ogr.py"

for shpfile in *.shp 
do 
   $org2ogrPath -skipfailures -clipsrc \
      ~/Desktop/PhiladelphiaBaseLayers/clipFeature/city_limits.shp \
      ~/Desktop/PhiladelphiaBaseLayers/clipped/"$shpfile" \
      ~/Desktop/PhiladelphiaBaseLayers/"$shpfile"
done

for shpfile in *.shp 
do 
   $ogr2ogrPath -skipfailures -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:3857 \
      ~/Desktop/PhiladelphiaBaseLayers/clipped/"$shpfile"
done
```

Comment: I'm not sure why I can't get this to run.  It has been driving me crazy. I know it should be simple.  This for some reason still does not work.  I don't know if my path is incorrect or what.  Also, are you supposed to type export or is that not necessary?

Comment: If you can get it working at your prompt, run `echo $PATH` and save the path. Then in the script, at line 2, add `export PATH="whatever it was"`

Comment: You can also change the first line to `#!/bin/bash -xv` and run it again and it will print each line as it is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Though it produced some strange errors about Topology Exceptions, this is the code that worked for me.

```
#!/bin/bash
#this is a bash file for conducting operations through ogr2ogr

cd ~/documents/PhiladelphiaBaseLayers

ogr2ogrPath="/library/frameworks/GDAL.framework/versions/1.11/programs/ogr2ogr"

for f in *.shp; do $ogr2ogrPath -skipfailures -clipsrc ~/documents/PhiladelphiaBaseLayers/clipFeature/city_limits.shp ~/documents/PhiladelphiaBaseLayers/clipped/$f ~/documents/PhiladelphiaBaseLayers/$f; done

for f in *.shp; do $ogr2ogrPath -skipfailures -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:3857 ~/documents/PhiladelphiaBaseLayers/clippedandprojected/$f ~/documents/PhiladelphiaBaseLayers/clipped/$f; done
```